# local network and different subnets

Tags: home-networking

Is there a way that my local machines that has address like 192.168.0.1 can talk to my local machines that has address like 10.0.0.1. All machines are in my local network?

Comment: Do you have a router or does one of the systems have two network adapters?  Any particular operating systems involved?

Comment: Umm... Why don't you use the same sub network for all your machines? Either switch all to 192... or all to 10...

Answer (score 0):

Even though they may be physically on the same network, 10.x.x.x and 192.168.x.x are different networks. You need something route traffic between them, like a router.

A problem you may run into is that both 192.168.x.x. and 10.x.x.x are considered non-routed addresses on the Internet (that's why people use them for personal networks), so a router may not be willing route these addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @techie007: "You need something [to] route traffic between [your networks], like a router."  However, this doesn't have to be a thing that has the word "Router" printed on it; it can be one of your computers.  (I assume that your "machines" are computers.)  You need to have at least one machine with two IP addresses: one on each of your networks.  If you happen to have a machine with two physical network interfaces, this should be straightforward.  Otherwise, you can (probably) assign multiple addresses to a single physical network interface.  In Windows, you can do this through the Control Panel.  (You will need to dig down a few levels; e.g., go to IPv4 Properties and then click on Advanced.)  In *nix you can use an `ip` or `ifconfig` command.  Then enable routing in that machine.  And you may need to tell the other machines to use this one as a router.

It would help us to answer your question if you would say what operating system(s) your machines are running.